# Jfree chart xy line implementation

Tags: java, graphics, plot, jfreechart

I want to plot 4 lines in one dataset but I cannot. Could any1 tell me what libs in need in jfree and how I can implement them in 1 chart

```
 public void visualise(){
 //visualise data
  XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Membrane mVolt");
XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("potassium_channel_n_gate_n");
XYSeries series3 = new XYSeries("sodium_channel_h_gate_h");
XYSeries series4 = new XYSeries("sodium_channel_m_gate_m");
//add data to charts
for(int l=0;l<301;l++){
series.add(tData[l], YData[0][l]);
series2.add(tData[l], YData[1][l]);
series3.add(tData[l], YData[2][l]);
series4.add(tData[l], YData[3][l]);
}
//create lines
XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
XYDataset xyDataset2 = new XYSeriesCollection(series2);
XYDataset xyDataset3 = new XYSeriesCollection(series3);
XYDataset xyDataset4 = new XYSeriesCollection(series4);

//visualize
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Membrane", "time","data",xyDataset,       PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
 JFreeChart chart2 = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Potassium Channel n", "time""data",xyDataset2,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
 JFreeChart chart3 = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Sodium Channel h", "time","data",xyDataset3, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
 JFreeChart chart4 = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Sodium Channel m", "time", "data",xyDataset4,   
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
//open window
ChartFrame frame1=new ChartFrame(" ",chart);
ChartFrame frame2=new ChartFrame(" ",chart2);
ChartFrame frame3=new ChartFrame(" ",chart3);
ChartFrame frame4=new ChartFrame(" ",chart4);

//make window
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.setSize(900,900);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.setSize(900,900);
frame3.setVisible(true);
frame3.setSize(900,900);
frame4.setVisible(true);
frame4.setSize(900,900);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/jfreechartdemo) shows how to add multiple series to a [`DefaultXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultXYDataset.html).