# How to create and add xy series dynamically to a xy data set?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to generate xy line chart graph with different dataset. I want to add 0 index of array and every increasing array index to a separate series.
I have tried so far

```
final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Kinectic Energy");
objBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String linee;
while((linee = objBufferedReader.readLine())!=null )
{ 
    System.out.println("in while loop");
    linee=linee.trim();
    String [] parts = linee.split("\\s+");
    int len=parts.length;
    double[] array = new double[len];
    for(int j=0; j<len;j++)
    {
         array[j]= Double.parseDouble(parts[j]);
    }
    for(int j=1; j<len;j++)
    {
         series.add(array[0],array[j]);
    }
}
```

"j" represent columns in a file.I want to do that

```
series.add(array[0],array[1]);
series1.add(array[0],array[2]);
series2.add(array[0],array[3]);     
XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
dataset.addSeries(series);
dataset.addSeries(series1);
dataset.addSeries(series2);
```

up to length variable dynamically. Please guide me how can I do that??

Comment: _different dataset_? Different from what? Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: I mean different series in one dataset. I want to create line chart of many xy datasets.

Comment: An  example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6193011/230513).

Comment: Thanks. I solved it through vectors  :)

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).